# Max function and brackets in Matlab

Tags: matlab, max

Why is it that the code:

> > [a,b] = max([1,2,3;4,5,6;7,8,9])

produces
a =

```
 7     8     9
```

b =

```
 3     3     3
```

Should a be the max number in each of the rows so 5,6,9 and b be the max number in each of the columns so 7,8,9?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

7, 8, 9 are the `max` in each column of your matrix, and 3, 3, 3 are the positions of that max number.

Vector 'a' stores the max numbers, and vector 'b' stores the indexes in each vector.

I suggest reading [matlab doc](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html) for more details if you want to get the max for each row.